# How to set up three js so as to get autocomplete in .vue file

Tags: visual-studio-code, three.js, vuejs3

I am using Vue js 3 and for a project I need to use three js. I downloaded the module using :-

```
npm install --save three
```

However I am not able to use vscode suggestions/autocomplete for the particular module.

Please note that the autocomplete/suggestions don’t work in .vue file but they work in .js (javascript file)

Comment: Not sure I understand your questions. If you import three.js into your component, you should have the full developer experience. I recommend to use TypeScript which should help you even more in this regard.

Comment: @Thomas I actually have the same issue but in vue 2.6.12